# Using zip to run all Observables

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I am trying to run a list of Observables either in parallel or series (doesn't matter, I just want them to actually run), something like so:

```
     Rx.Observable.zip([

        Rx.Observable.timer(100),
        Rx.Observable.timer(200),
        Rx.Observable.timer(205)

    ])
        .do(function (val) {
           console.log('val =>', val);
        })
        .subscribe()
```

the logging statement never gets executed and I don't know why. I even tried throwing in a concatAll for good measure.

```
        Rx.Observable.zip([

            Rx.Observable.timer(100),
            Rx.Observable.timer(200),
            Rx.Observable.timer(205)

        ])
        .concatAll()
            .do(function (val) {
               console.log('val =>', val);
            })
            .subscribe()
```

anyone know what's wrong?

What I want to do is the following, which actually works:

```
   return Rx.Observable.range(0, count)
        .map(function (i) {
            return q.enq('foo ' + i);
        })
        .concatAll()
        .subscribe()
```

but I am trying to figure out how to do the same with zip or merge like I attempted at above above.

Comment: I also tried Rx.Observable.merge() but that returned an array, not an Observable, even though the docs said it would return an Observable.

Answer (score 2):

[`zip`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip) takes a variable number of observables; it does not take an array:

```
Rx.Observable.zip(
    Rx.Observable.timer(100),
    Rx.Observable.timer(200),
    Rx.Observable.timer(205)
)
.do(function (val) {
    console.log('val =>', val);
})
.subscribe();
```

However, if you have an array of observables in a variable, to use the array with `zip` you could spread its elements:

```
const array = [
    Rx.Observable.timer(100),
    Rx.Observable.timer(200),
    Rx.Observable.timer(205)
];
Rx.Observable.zip(...array)
.do(function (val) {
    console.log('val =>', val);
})
.subscribe();
```

Comment: aye yi yi, let me try that thanks, do you know why merge wouldn't work in zip's place? Maybe merge does not take an array either...

Comment: From memory, most take a variable number of observable arguments.